# wordpress camera image capture and save

Tags: php, wordpress, webcam, image-capture

I 'm currently having a project that uses Advanced Custom Fields on the frontend helping the user to upload his photo and store it in a post.
What i would like to add is having the choice of instantly capture a photo with a webcam and save as a second option.
Is there any way to make this possible?

Comment: What you have tried. A suggestion Use new html 5 api key to activate camera.

Comment: Is that possible?Have any available documentation in mind?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: doesn't seem very reliable...demo not working on my chrome...